# How to make textbox optional in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've been trying to figure out how I can make a textbox optional. I've tried the javascript method (value).removeAtt('required'). I've also tried removing [Required] from ViewModel it worked however when you do enter text it comes up in the database as null.
What other ways can i approach this.

Viewmodel

```
[Required]
[Display(Name="comment")]
public string comment{get; set;]
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(QuestionToAnswerViewModel questionToAnswerVm)
        {
            var questionToAnswer = _questionAnswerService.GetAnswerById(questionToAnswerVm.QuestionId);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if(questionToAnswerVm.AdditionalComment != null)
                {
                    questionToAnswer.Comment = questionToAnswerVm.AdditionalComment;
                }
                else
                {
                    questionToAnswer.Comment = null;
                }
```

View

```
    <div id ="additionalComment" class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdditionalComment,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdditionalComment,new { @class = "form-control"})

        </div>
    </div
```

Comment: Are you saying that when you load the view you see NULL in the textbox? Or are you saying it is not saving the field when you put something in the text box? I think we need to see more of the view and controller code to determine why you are always getting null, but removing the [Required] is what you want to do

Comment: @mathis1337 It doesn't save the field. That's when I remove the required from the viewmodel.

Comment: Can you add a .Value to the end of the field when you remove the Required?

Comment: @mathis1337 Yes. But it doesn't show in the database.

Comment: Oh also are you using EF, is so after removing the required you will want to create a migration and migrate that to DB. OTherwise I don't think it can save to DB

Answer (score 0):

If you still specify required attribute in Models/View Models 
Specify this n your model file as

```
public string? comment {get;set;}
```

also you can specify this line in your global.asax file in application_onstart event

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check

1. Remove required from model.
2. Check if id matches with view and model.
   Put a break point in controller and check if value is getting passed from view to controller.